# Can an Immediate action be taken after an attack hits but before damage is rolled?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, immediate-actions

So I intend to take [Wave shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wave-shield). It takes an immediate action to activate.

I already know questions will come up with my DM when I try to use this ability...

The way I understand the mechanics immediate actions are allowed at any time. So I intend to use Wave Shield once an attack connects and damage dice are to be rolled.

So first off is this correct? I believe it is since immediate actions have no restrictions on when they can be used outside of having already used a swift action or immediate action on your turn, or having used your immediate action for the next turn already!

The second question is slightly more awkward, will this casting of Wave Shield provoke an attack of opportunity? I can't find much on the matter besides [this table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#Table-Actions-in-Combat)

It is practically a sidenote that mentions spells with a cast time of a standard action. Does that mean this spell is immune to attacks of opportunity?

Comment: Have you read the posting guidelines yet? This is two questions, not one, as you yourself acknowledged, so they should be posted accordingly, perhaps cross-linked to note they are related, but not posted as a single question. I recommend you simply cut and paste the last two paragraphs into a new question, deleting them from here, and take out the first few words about it being a second question.

Comment: I actually went through the help and did not see any guidelines on limiting to one question. Where did you see it? Although I can see the inherent value in sticking to a single subject.

Comment: Yep, it's a practical quality-of-service/content concern rather than a hard rule. Multiple questions in one question-post lead to the answer being spread across multiple answer-posts, and the voting system doesn't handle that well. Just split it: Cut the last two paragraphs and past them into a new question called "Does casting Wave Shield provoke Attacks of Opportunity?"

Comment: I can't mark this as a duplicate because it's two separate questions, one of which duplicates [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/21862/8610) yet the other, I think, is unasked elsewhere. I'm voting to close as unclear until the question's narrowed.

Comment: Actually I saw that question and the tags are for 3.5 D&D not pathfinder, although admittedly I do not know how much difference between the two there is on this subject.